# Skew Normal Distribution (Skewness vs alpha or a Parameter) - Generating N integers (Python SciPy)

Tags: python, scipy, skew

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a sample of N=10 numbers that have skewness 0.2; currently using Python's scipy library.

```
>>> x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> skew_norm = skewnorm.pdf(x, a=0.2, loc=0, scale=1)
>>> skew_norm
array([0.39894228, 0.4035167 , 0.40301   , 0.39744225, 0.3870234 ,
       0.37214011, 0.35333193, 0.3312589 , 0.30666315, 0.28032778])
>>> stats.skew(skew_norm)
-0.7703395748152717
```

I'm hoping to get 10 floats between 0 and 1 that are normalized (sum of 1) and have skewness value of 0.2. But it seems like checking for the skewness value gives a different result. Isn't the `a` here the alpha or skewness parameter, according to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html. But why does it give a different result? Seems like the skewness is wrong. Does anyone know how how I can generate a set of 10 floats between 0 and 1 (normalized summing to 1) such that the skew is 0.2 (i.e. a skewed normal distribution). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check
Skewnorm.stats
That just uses a to get the first four moments of the skewed pdf generated. I am not sure but what i understand is the  parameter a is not really the skewness of the distribution created but some shaping factor.